# Unexpected token error with jsDOM and Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, jsdom

I'm trying to render chartsjs on the server through jsDom. 
I have a working version using node.js & Express. 
Currently on a Meteor project whenever I add the following code

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
```

I get the following error:

```
W20170615-20:30:17.440(2)? (STDERR) packages\modules.js:397
W20170615-20:30:17.456(2)? (STDERR) const { URL } = require("whatwg-url");
W20170615-20:30:17.460(2)? (STDERR)       ^
W20170615-20:30:17.461(2)? (STDERR)
W20170615-20:30:17.463(2)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
W20170615-20:30:17.465(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.j
s:53:16)
W20170615-20:30:17.470(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\x\x\x\x\x
pp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:331:30
W20170615-20:30:17.472(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20170615-20:30:17.473(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\x\K
x\x\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev
_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20170615-20:30:17.475(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\x\x\x\x\x
pp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:158:5
W20170615-20:30:17.476(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\x\x\x\x\x
pp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:387:5
W20170615-20:30:17.478(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (C:\x\x\x
p\x\x\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12)
W20170615-20:30:17.479(2)? (STDERR)     at C:\x\x\x\x\x
pp\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:386:11
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Versions 
 - nodejs: v7.8
 - jsDom: 11.0.0
 - meteor: 1.5

To replicate the issue do the following:

1. run meteor create --full jsDomTest
2. cd jsDomTest
3. meteor npm install
4. npm install jsdom --save
5. in the root server folder add the following line `var jsdom = require('jsdom');`
6. run meteor

I am not sure at the moment how to approach this problem.
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you try and post a simple console application that demonstrates the problem? I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @akaphenom Thanks for the reply. I added to my original post step to replicate. I just ran those steps myself and same issue.

Comment: Did you execute `meteor npm install` to install all required modules?

Comment: @Khang Yes, the above replication assumes that is done.

Comment: I do not see that command in the above steps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an unresolved bug with JSDOM's newer versions. I've had the same problem with this in an Express.js app I was writing. The problem disappears if you change to version 9.0.0 (in the package.json) and then update your app (npm update ...) Or if you are able to update your Node.js version, then that could also solve the problem (I think Meteor.js uses an older version of Node.js).

At the least, this works for Node.js. It should in theory work for Meteor.js, which is based on Node.js, although its a long time since I've used Meteor.js, so matters might have moved on.

Comment: I did forget to remember :) that meteor's own node version is sitting at v4.8 and jsdom does say on its documents it requires v6 > for jsdom v11.0. So settings jsdom to v9 is the fix. Much appreciated.